# how to handle the exception when the DB is down while reading the mesage from kafka topic

Tags: apache-kafka

In my spring boot application i am  reading the message from kafka topic and saving the message in to HBase.

in case the DB is down and the message is consumed from the topic , how should i ensure that the message is  not lost. can someone share me a sample code.

Comment: Gary Russell covered this in depth here
https://www.confluent.io/blog/spring-for-apache-kafka-deep-dive-part-1-error-handling-message-conversion-transaction-support/

Comment: message will not lost it will exist in kafka and when your DB get up then you need to just change the offset, it will work properly.

Answer (score 1):

If your code encounters an error during the processing of a record, you as the developer, are responsible for handling retries or error catching. spring-kafka can't capture errors outside of the Kafka API for you.

That being said, Kafka will not remove the record just because it's consumed until it fully expires off the topic. You should definitely set `enable.auto.commit` to false and commit your own offsets after a successful database action, at the expense of potential duplicated records in hbase

I would also like to point out that you should probably be using Kafka Connect, which is meant to integrate external systems to Kafka, not a plain consumer.